# Maven plugin for gathering source code statistics

Tags: open-source, maven-plugin, code-statistics

Our project is based on J2EE and we would like to know if there is a open source maven-plugin which either integrates with cloc (Refer [How can I measure source code statistics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353631/source-code-statistics)) or other tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Sonar](http://sonar.codehaus.org/) for that!

As you can see in the [demo site](http://nemo.sonarsource.org/), when this tool analyses your project, it provides a lot of statistics (using their internal tool, Sonar Squid which is a replacement of the old JavaNCSS) :

[alt text http://sonar.codehaus.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/sonar-squid.jpg](http://sonar.codehaus.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/sonar-squid.jpg)